# DRY Multiple same associations in rails Model

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, metaprogramming

In my model, I have multiple has_one associations like

```
has_one  :t1_for_self_order, -> { t1_for_self_order }, as: :source, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :source,
          class_name: 'Spree::PriceMapping'
has_one  :shipping_charges_for_t1, -> { shipping_charges_for_t1 }, as: :source, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :source,
          class_name: 'Spree::PriceMapping'
has_one  :t2_for_self_order, -> { t2_for_self_order }, as: :source, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :source,
          class_name: 'Spree::PriceMapping'
has_one  :shipping_charges_for_t2, -> { shipping_charges_for_t2 }, as: :source, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :source,
          class_name: 'Spree::PriceMapping'
has_one  :minimum_value_for_gifting, -> { minimum_value_for_gifting }, as: :source, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :source,
          class_name: 'Spree::PriceMapping'
has_one  :international_fulfillment_fees, -> { international_fulfillment_fees }, as: :source, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :source,
          class_name: 'Spree::PriceMapping'
```

you notice that only the association name with the same scope name is different in all the associations but the rest of the content is same.

So I want to write a function that will remove all these repetitions.
I think it can be possible with Meta programming but I'm not sure how to do this

Moreover, I also have an array of nested attributes which we can use.

```
    THRESHOLD_INTENT = ["t1_for_self_order", "shipping_charges_for_t1", "t2_for_self_order", "shipping_charges_for_t2",
                    "minimum_value_for_gifting", "international_fulfillment_fees", "menu_customization_fee",
                    "total_menu_customization_fee_cap", "video_message_fee", "total_video_message_fee_cap",
                    "swag_price", "box_types_with_price", "customization_box_types_with_price", "custom_note_fee",
                    "non_us_fees"]
```

I like to do it in this way

```
THRESHOLD_INTENT.each do |t_intent|
  has_one  t_intent.to_sym, as: :source, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :source, class_name: 'Spree::PriceMapping'
end
```

But how can i pas the scope in this like

> -> { t1_for_self_order }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over a list of association names and call `has_one` with all the parameters on each item. `send(association)` is needed to call an association scope as a method.

```rb
ASSOCIATIONS = [:t1_for_self_order, :shipping_charges_for_t1, :t2_for_self_order, :shipping_charges_for_t2, :minimum_value_for_gifting, :international_fulfillment_fees]

ASSOCIATIONS.each do |association|
  has_one association, -> { send(association) }, as: :source, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :source, class_name: 'Spree::PriceMapping'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the common attributes, something like

```
relationship_attributes = { as: :source, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :source, class_name: 'Spree::PriceMapping' }

has_one :t1_for_self_order, -> { t1_for_self_order }, relationship_attributes
has_one :shipping_charges_for_t1, -> { shipping_charges_for_t1 }, relationship_attributes
has_one :t2_for_self_order, -> { t2_for_self_order }, relationship_attributes
has_one :shipping_charges_for_t2, -> { shipping_charges_for_t2 }, relationship_attributes
has_one :minimum_value_for_gifting, -> { minimum_value_for_gifting }, relationship_attributes
has_one  :international_fulfillment_fees, -> { international_fulfillment_fees }, relationship_attributes
```

I would not use metaprogramming, it can make it difficult to read

Comment: with this i still have 12 repeated has_one associations i just updated my question can you please have a look @javiyu